# How do you close a mesh

Tags: meshlab

I'm attempting to make a mesh from a point cloud but every time I use Poisson surface reconstruction, it doesn't create a full solid, it leaves the bottom open. I've run out of ideas on how to fill the rest of the area. I would like to 3D print this but it won't import anywhere unless it's a full solid.

[image: my model]

Comment: Hi @Jack. Did this answer help with your problem closing a mesh? If so, please mark the question as solved to help others to know that was correct. If not, please let us know what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the filter **Close holes** (located in the menu `Filters`->`Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction`) and increase the default value of parameter `Max size to be closed`

[image: Close Holes Filter]